# How can I set the insets of a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, insets

Is there a way to set the insets of a `JFrame`?
I tried

```
frame.getContentPane().getInsets().set(10, 10, 10, 10);
```

and

```
frame.getInsets().set(10, 10, 10, 10);
```

but none of them seem to work.

Comment: If using a `JPanel` for the content pane, simply `panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));`

Comment: @AndrewThompson If the OP is asking about setting the insets on the frame why not just override `getInsets()`?

Comment: @Dan 1) [Is “Don't do it” a valid answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer) 2) [Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) 3) It is rare that we can make an application using a single layout, so may as well create a main panel as content pane. 4) But apart from those three compelling reasons, I guess not.

Answer (score 28):

```
JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();

Border padding = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10);

contentPanel.setBorder(padding);

yourFrame.setContentPane(contentPanel);
```

So basically, `contentPanel` is the main container of your frame.

Comment: I didn't use the method `getContentPane`, I created a `JPanel` name `contentPanel` to have access to `setBorder` method.

Answer (score 4):

Overriding the `Insets` of `JFrame` would not be the soultion to your actual problem. 
To answer your question, you cannot set the Insets of `JFrame`. You should extend JFrame and override the `getInsets` method to give the insets you require.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create an Object of LayOutConstraint and set its Insets.
Like in below example I have used GridBagLayout() and used GridBagConstraint() object.

```
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5); // top, left, bottom, right
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;

    // Row 1
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
    panel.add(isAlgoEnabledLabel, c);
```

Answer (score 0):

As this question does not have a definitive answer yet you can do it like [basiljames](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1653776/basiljames) said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14117874/4601149). The correct way to do it would be to extend a `JFrame` and then override the `getInsets()` method.

For example

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Insets;

public class JFrameInsets extends JFrame {
    @Override
    public Insets getInsets() {
        return new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
    }

    private JFrameInsets()  {
        super("Insets of 10");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setMinimumSize(getSize());
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JFrameInsets();
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not a good way, because the insets are ruined in case of resize

Answer (score 0):

you can create a main `JPanel` and insert everything else into it.

Then you can use `BorderFactory` to create `EmptyBorder` or `LineBorder`.

see this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17925693/8953378