# How to add padding to a JPanel with a border

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, border, padding

I want to add padding to some `JPanel`s. I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5328475/1590323

It worked fine for a panel without a border. But how do I do it for a panel that already has a border? (A `TitledBorder` in this case)

I tried:

```
JPanel mypanel = new MyPanel(); // Panel that I am going to add a TitledBorder to, but needs padding
mypanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));
JPanel mypanel_container = new JPanel();
TitledBorder border = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder(), "My panel");
border.setTitleJustification(TitledBorder.LEADING);
mypanel_container.setBorder(border);
mypanel_container.add(mypanel);
this.add(mypanel_container);
```

(In short: Adding an `EmptyBorder` to the panel that should have a `TitledBorder`, then make another panel with the `TitledBorder` and add the first panel to that, and then use that panel)

But then I got way too large padding that ignored the contructor values of the `EmptyBorder`.

So **how do I add padding to a JPanel with a graphical border?**

Comment: +1, to the hard work you had done before posting the question :-) though, as stated previously this will come in some time

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can take a look at [`CompoundBorder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/border/CompoundBorder.html).

> A composite Border class used to compose two Border objects into a
>   single border by nesting an inside Border object within the insets of
>   an outside Border object. For example, this class may be used to add
>   blank margin space to a component with an existing decorative border:
>
> ```
> Border border = comp.getBorder();
> Border margin = new EmptyBorder(10,10,10,10);
> comp.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(border, margin));
> ```

Of course, you can also use [`BorderFactory#createCompoundBorder(border, margin)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BorderFactory.html).

Comment: Thanks, `CompoundBorder` was just what I needed!